# Looking for a Overlay UI marking program for screencasting

Tags: gui, automation, screen-recording, screenshot, lua

I make lots of quick gifs but I cannot annotate them that well. The program needs to do following:

1. Hold Rightclick (or some modifiers + rightclick) on mouse
2. Draw Strokes
3. Strokes stay on screen until right → context menu → remove strokes

There's a program based in Lua that does this called StrokePlus. Another called pointerfocus as well

https://alternativeto.net/browse/search?q=strokeplus

https://alternativeto.net/software/pointerfocus/

Example:

[image: StrokePlus]

The only problem here is that I want the strokes to stay on the screen until I tell it to be removed off[image: Example]

This would massively simplify and allow me to make faster, concise, annotated gifs

I know Lua has all the capabilities to overlay a GUI based program for this in windows based OS

Would anyone know what programs I could use here? I'm not looking for something like techsmith snagit or camtasia studio, it literally just needs to be stroke marks on a screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it

https://alternativeto.net/software/epic-pen/

its called epic pen

it lets you do things like this:
[image]